# undefined function in hmtl/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Just playing around with functions..

The live server shows undefined.
However; when I just run the javascript code-the correct greetings show.

Why is this?
What can I do to fix it?

```
const today = new Date();
let now = today.getHours(); //0-23
let time;
/*morning: 0300 - 1100
*morning >= 0300 && morning < 11
*afternoon 1100-1900
*afternoon >= 11 && afternoon < 19
*evening 1900 - 0300
*evening >= 19 && evening < 3
 */

if (now >= 5 && now < 11) {
  time = 'morning';
} else if (now >= 11 && now < 17) {
  time = 'afternoon';
} else if (now >= 17 && now < 23) {
  time = 'night';
} else {
  time = 'sleep';
}

//console.log(time);

function greeting() {
  if (time === 'morning') {
    console.log('Good Morning!');
    console.log('I love you!');
    console.log("You're doing GREAT!");
    console.log('Nice butt!');
  } else if (time ==='afternoon') {
    console.log('Good afternoon!');
    console.log("You're a genius!");
    console.log('Just keep swimming!');
    console.log('Progress not perfection!');
  } else if (time === 'night') {
    console.log('Goodnight, Princess!');
    console.log('Time for a nightcap.');
    console.log ('Sleep tight!');
    console.log ('Get NAKED!');
  } else {
    console.log('GO TF\' TO SLEEP'); 
    console.log('GO TF\' TO SLEEP');
    console.log('GO TF\' TO SLEEP');
    console.log('GO TF\' TO SLEEP');
  }
}

//greeting();
document.write('<h1>' + greeting() + '</h1>');
```

??

Comment: Please do not put in padding text to get by the question editor limit, it is there for a reason

Comment: `greeting()` does not return a value, so `undefined` is returned.  This turns `'<h1>' + greeting() + '</h1>'` into `<h1>undefined</h1>` .

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` prints to the console (`F12` in normal browsers). You probably want to replace all `console.log()` with `document.write('<yourTag>Message</yourTag>');`.

Otherwise, if you want to use the output of the function the you can create an empty string variable and concat your messages and return them.

```
function functionName() {
    let result = '';
    result = result + 'my Test';
    result = result + ' my Test 2';
    return result;
}
```

Of course you can use structures control structures (if/else) with both ways.

Answer (score 0):

greeting() method does not return anything that's why you are getting undefined

```
function greeting(){
    return 'Say Hello!'
}
```

Now this will shows you

```
<h1>Say Hello!</h1>
```